# Name disappears between directory view and details view

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm having a problem creating a shared contact.
When I create it, everything works fine and I can find my contact in the domain directory.
But when I click on it to get the detailed information, its first and last name have disappeared.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Directory view:

[image: directory view]

Detail view:

[image: detail view]

As you can see, the name is missing from the detailed view...